# Strange generic method call with explicit generic type behaviour

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I have a non-generic class with a generic method. Generic type on this method defines output type and can't be inferred from usage so I have to explicitly provide generic type. Sometimes this type is passed on from generic caller's method type parameter, but in one instance I have to explicitly provide it myself.

The problem is when I call my explicitly provided generic type method call it seems that it doesn't get executed and returns a completely irrelevant type. I can't debug into this call and get invalid results. But it doesn't break execution which is especially strange. When the same method is called from elsewhere where generic type is passed on from caller's generic method type, everything seems to work as per definition.

**I'm completely lost what's going on.**

My method definition in the interface (and is implemented later in the class):

```
TRecord Update<TRecord>(int recordId, int? categoryId, string categoryName, string title)
    where TRecord : Record;
```

My `Record` class is non-abstract and and there's only one type that inherits from it:

```
public class Record : ProtectedEntity
{
    ...
}

public class RelatedRecord<T> : Record
{
    public IList<T> Related { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

I'm calling my method doing this:

```
var record = myRepo.Update<Record>(...);
```

When execution gets to this line I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to debug into it, but execution just jumps to the next sentence. When I check my `record` variable it's not of type `Record` but rather `System.String`, having the value of parameter `categoryName`. This means that something does get executed but it's definitely not the body of my generic method.

The strange thing is that everywhere else the same call works as expected.

**How can this be explained and what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Looks curious. Can you extract some of your code to MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)?

Comment: at the compile time what's the type of record ? what happens when you try to access a member of `Record` or `string` using `record` at runtime ?

Comment: does `record.GetType().FullName` return `System.String` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes it does return `System.String`. :S

Comment: @Robert k; can you also check `typeof(Record).FullName`? what is that?

Comment: @Selman22: At compile time when I hover `var` beside the `record` variable Visual Studio correctly shows type `Record`. If I try to access any members during runtime it of course throws an exception about non existing members.

Comment: @MarcGravell: doing `typeof(Record).FullName` correctly returns my full type name including namespaces as it should. As stated in the question - all calls to this method work when generic type is passed on from caller's generic method type param. When I explicitly specify type in this call (correct one that should work as expected) it doesn't work.

Comment: "all calls to this method work when generic type is passed on from caller's generic method type param." - do you mean as `Update<T>(...)`? or `Update(...)`?

Comment: @MarcGravell: The first one... Type is being provided but is passed on from caller's generic type. Higher in the call stack this type is correctly inferred by compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are saying, including the comment:

> If I try to access any members during runtime it of course throws an exception about non existing members.

it sounds like either a compiler bug or JIT bug. That means to diagnose it we need more knowledge of the compiler you are using (exact version) and/or the JIT you are using. In the case of a compiler bug, it *may* suffice if you can simply show the IL that has been generated, if you're familiar with that.

Note that the most recent VS preview includes an entirely new JIT (RyuJIT) and *enables it by default system-wide*, so if you have installed the VS preview, that would be my guess. If so, you can disable it trivially to check.

---

Note the other option here is something like a `using` alias that aliases `Record` to be `System.String`, or aliases `var` to be `System.String` (plus some implicit conversion operators, etc). These are unlikely, but I've seen it happen ;p

Edit: the above is ruled out by your comment:

> doing typeof(Record).FullName correctly returns my full type name including namespaces as it should.

So we are left with compiler bug or JIT bug.

---

If this is a RyuJIT bug, here are the options to disable it (I suggest using the config one first, as it is the easiest to do):

1. As an environment variable: set COMPLUS_useLegacyJit=1
2. In the registry: Set HKLM or HKCU, Software\Microsoft.NETFramework. Key name: useLegacyJit. Type: REG_DWORD. Value: 1
3. In an app.exe.config file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <runtime>
       <useLegacyJit enabled="1" />
     </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```

(these come from a separate discussion with MS that I had previously)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 4. If I open VS2012 Command prompt (although I don't have VS 2012 installed and there's no matching command prompt for 2013) and type **csc** it says: *Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5*

Comment: @RobertKoritnik can you carve it down to a minimal bit of code that is reproducible? I would love to take a deeper look, but that demands a repro

Comment: I could try writing an example, but if it's a JIT bug it will be hard to repro such source code because if it was easy there would be many developers facing the same issue/bug. but I can try... Also mind that I'm (apparently) not using the latest compiler as I'm not using VS2015...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik another fun thing to try: make the project explicit x86 (not AnyCPU) and try it, then make it explicit x64 and try it; does it fail in both? or just one?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik re "many developers" - no, that is not necessarily the case; JIT and compiler bugs can be *incredibly* contextual and specific - it is entirely possible that it is very very rare. I reported a RyuJIT bug a month or so ago: I'm pretty sure nobody else would have hit the same scenario for many months.

Comment: that was an excellent suggestion. Everything's fine in x86 but doesn't work in x64. :) What now? How should I mitigate this to keep my code work as expected? The thing is that my app is deployed on Azure which may use the same compiler or maybe not... :( Just for the info... If I check the **Optimize code** in x64 it also works, although I can't debug this particular method but I can debug downcalls and I can confirm they're being executed as expected.

Comment: How can we pinpoint which part is buggy? Compiler or JIT? When I look at IL code (in ILSpy) seems fine to my eyes. But I'm no IL expert... Looking at compiled C# code in ILSpy seems fine. Should I be looking at it any differently to see whether compiler is buggy?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik if you post the IL, I can tell you whether it is the compiler or the JIT ;p

Comment: @RobertKoritnik also, you've already answered this actually: the x64 vs x86 test is pretty much intended to help clarify this; it strongly suggests that the bug is in the x64 JIT; the IL should be the same either way. If it failed in both, then *probably* the compiler (although it could have been a bug that is common to both JITs, but that is rarer)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik in case this is a RyuJIT issue (perhaps from the azure tools), I've included (see edit) instructions for disabling it

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting a runtime type exception, I might suspect a bug in the Visual Studio debugger that I've run into.  If you have two locally scoped variable with the same name in the same method, the debugger can confuse them:

```
private void DoSomething(int x)
{
    {
        var s = "STRING!";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    {
        var s = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

I don't know if the above example will actually reproduce the issue, but I've seen behavior from the debugger where you mouse over the second s and it shows it as "STRING!", not 5.  That would be the first thing I would check, that you don't have another local variable in the same method named "record".

Comment: Unfortunately there's only one variable with this name in executing method's scope.